# Designing MVC application: add in persistence and UI later?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

It feels comparatively easy to implement a bunch of classes that will eventually be part of a UI and need to be persisted without dealing with things like Hibernate or Spring and then, once tested and working in unit and integration tests, add in Hibernate and Spring later. In fact, I think maybe that is the correct approach. But is it realistic? If you know from the outset that a class would have to be persisted and indeed multiple classes which have complex relationships have to be saved to a database, would that not in practice affect the design? Or can you actually just get all the logic working, ignoring the eventual persistence and UI and add it in later?

Comment: Didn't get your question? Please explain in detail.How persisting classes without the help of Hibernate would make things easy(In context with JDBC)?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned developing without UI and persistence layer. Then the only layer of prominence which remains is Service layer.

If you are going ahead with implementing only the service layer its NOT a bad idea. Reason, now-a-days there are many RESTful services. They do not have a UI. But on the other hand they do have persistence. However, the process of exposing them as RESTful services,determining their input/output format(JSON schema mostly) and testing their integration with any other system can still be done without a persistence layer.

This is not to say that your service layer will also be exposed as RESTful service. Even if it is not - while implementing your services you need to -

- design your service granularity(fine or course)
- design your DTOs(Data Transfer Objects) which will be responsible for carrying data from UI layer to service layer where they will be converted to domain objects(but this conversion to domain classes can wait till you implement persistence)
- unit test your service classes and make sure business logic is implemented correctly

Considering there are a lot of things that can be done without a UI & persistence layer - I would say go ahead - design and even start implementing.

But keep in mind only one caveat - keep some buffer integration time when you integrate your service layer with UI & persistence layers.